# got error "CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition" in dotnetopenauth mvc sample

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth

I am using MSVS 2012. I compiled DNOA with no errors. I set startup 
project to OAuth2/OAuthAuthorizationServer. It runs ok. I created the sql 
db ok. The I tried the "login" link and I get this:

\samples\OAuthAuthorizationServer\Views\Account\LogOn.aspx(15,68): error 
CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'UserSuppliedIdentifier' 
and no extension method 'UserSuppliedIdentifier' accepting a first argument 
of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an 
assembly reference?)
I am very new to OAuth (MVC also). So this might be an easy/dumb question.

Comment: I am running into the same thing.  Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution [here](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/adding-openid-authentication-to-your-asp-net-mvc-4-application/).

And also check the comments from distantcam.

> I had some issues with an OpenID provider that only populated the
>   FullName field. This caused several null ref exceptions.
>
> The way I fixed it was to update the OpenIdUser.addClaimInfo() method
>   like this.

```
private void addClaimInfo(ClaimsResponse claim, string identifier)
{
    Email = claim.Email ?? "";
    FullName = claim.FullName ?? "";
    Nickname = claim.Nickname ?? claim.Email ?? claim.FullName ?? "";
    IsSignedByProvider = claim.IsSignedByProvider;
    ClaimedIdentifier = identifier;
}
```